# Formula for number of latin rectangles with 2 rows

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square

So i am preparing for exam in cominatorics and reading a textbook, and this is the task can't solve:

> Find formula for normalized 2 row latin rectangle number $L(n,2)$
> The problem is I am really stuck at this problem.
> Where L(n,2) is the number of normalized 2 row latin rectangles.

Could help me to solve this task? I am really stuck at this problem

Comment: More people could respond if you define $L(n,2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is closely related to derangements

\begin{array}{c|lc}
n & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8   \\
\hline
L(n,2) & 1 & 1 & 3 & 11 & 53 & 309 & 2119 
\end{array}

$$ L(n,2) = \frac{!n}{n-1} $$

where a simple trick to calculate deragenements

$$!n = \lfloor \frac{n!}e + \frac12 \rfloor $$

see [ref here](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/EJC/Volume_17/PDF/v17i1a1.pdf)